# Распарсить строку с названиями приложений

Tags: objective-c

В переменную приходит такая строка, Нужно ее распарсить и взять название приложений.
[image: это строка]

Как ее обработать чтобы взять определнные значение:SLGoogleAuth HalfTunes TheBackgrounder Calculator.  Заранее благодарен за любую помощь.

Comment: от `.app` влево до слэша

Comment: да от .app влево до слэша

Comment: можно строки в виде текста а не скриншота?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/i0XnCK7W

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Class LSApplicationWorkspace_class = objc_getClass("LSApplicationWorkspace");
SEL selector = NSSelectorFromString(@"defaultWorkspace");
NSObject *workspace = [LSApplicationWorkspace_class performSelector:selector];
SEL selectorALL = NSSelectorFromString(@"allApplications");
NSArray *list = [workspace performSelector:selectorALL];
[list enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *_Nonnull stop) {
    NSLog(@"item %@", [obj valueForKey:@"_bundleExecutable"]);
}];
```

Comment: не подскажите как связать с моим кодом?

Comment: покажите свой код, будем думать

Comment: pastebin.com/i0XnCK7W

Comment: исправил ответ.

Comment: Great thanks, хотелось бы еще что небудь почитать на эту тему ,так как копипастить нехочется копипастить

Comment: какая именно часть кода не понятна?

Comment: Вот это что делает [list enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id  _Nonnull obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *_Nonnull stop) {
    NSLog(@"item %@", [obj valueForKey:@"_bundleExecutable"]);
}]; И как это все вывести в таблицу

Comment: берет массив list и проходится по всем его объектам. и для каждого объекта выполняет код в скобках. при этом в блок текущий объект передается как obj и его номер как idx

Comment: А как его обратно сделать массивом чтобы передать в UITableview